# Coloring different levels in gvis Column Chart

Tags: r, google-visualization, shiny, googlevis

I am trying to use gvis Column chart in R shiny. I have just 1 column with multiple levels and I want to color different levels with different colors. I,m not able to achieve this.

Eg. Data

```
     Gender Count
   1 Female   309
   2   Male   280
```

My Code :

```
        colGvis <- gvisColumnChart(reqData)
```

Output :

[image]

I want different colors for male and female.

If there are other gvis charts that can do the same, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`googleVis` requires you add column [roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available) to your `data.frame` for aesthetics mapping.

```
# Add role column
reqData$Count.style = c('blue','green') 

colGvis<-gvisColumnChart(reqData,
                         xvar = "Gender",
                         yvar = c("Count","Count.style")) # Include in yvar

plot(colGvis)
```

[image]

Comment: It worked perfect. Thanks. I was just wondering if the legend could be changed as well

Comment: I'd simply get rid of it by adding `options = list( legend = "none")`. The difference is already 1. labeled on the axis, 2. differentiated by colour. We don't need the same information repeated  for a third time.